# Location of AppData for VSTO plugin for MS-Word

Tags: windows, vsto

I have developed a VSTO plugin for MS-Word, and while using it with Desktop version of Office suit, the data is properly saved in **appdata** directory,

But one of the user is using same plugin with **Trusted Microsoft Store App** version of MS-Word, which comes by default with new licenced Win 10 version.

Now the problem I am facing is, I had created a SQLCE database in appdata directory, and VSTO plugin saves some information in it, for normal word its working fine, but for app store version, its successfully saving data but 
its not reflected in that database.

So, at which location MS-Word is saving appdata?

Update 1: Using following code, I am retrieving the path

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\MyAppData"
```

And strange thing is that, even if I delete **MyAppData** from regular location still its working, means its using some other location to store data.

Update 2:

Using above mentioned code, I get following paths,

From **Windows Store Word**,

> C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Roaming\MyAppData

From **Desktop Word**,

> C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Roaming\MyAppData

So how can I make Windows Store app, point to normal **AppData** location?

Comment: Are you building the path to the database at runtime or is it a setting/variable?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: @aduguid I had update question with code to retrieve appdata directory path, I am dynamically creating path whenever being used.

Answer (score 0):

Since the functionality still works when the folder is deleted, you are probably constructing the path differently when creating and writing to it than when you are reading it.

For path problems like this, the best way to diagnose it is to debug it, or add logging, to find out what exact path is used for each operation. In this case, when: A) Creating the database file B) Modifying it C) Trying to read it.

By the way, using `Path.Combine` is preferable to string concatenation.

Comment: Hellow Chris, I was able to find the paths, and updated same in my question, but using same code I am getting different paths, strange but true, it varies with version of Word I am using (Windows Store App / Desktop App), I had even used Path.Combine but results are same.

Comment: It seems like this difference is intentional. You will probably have to put your files somewhere else, or make non-interoperability between the 2 deployments a known limitation.

Comment: Isn't there any way to configure, the location of AppData for Windows App Store apps.

Comment: I highly doubt it.